# Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries or apps that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I've created a new project in Android Studio, but when I run the application to test it, it shows me this error:

```
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-33.

      Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
      plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

      Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
      plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
      compileSdk of at least 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).
```

I don't know what is going on, but currently I'm using the latest updates and libraries.

These are dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

This is the code:

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AllBook extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView bookRecView;
    BookRecAdapter bookAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_book);
        bookAdapter = new BookRecAdapter(this);
        bookRecView = findViewById(R.id.booksRecView);
        bookRecView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
        bookRecView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book(1, "1Q84", "Haruki Murakumi", 135, "https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1483103331l/10357575.jpg", "1Q84 is a novel written by Japanese writer Haruki Murakami, first published in three volumes in Japan in 2009–10."
        , "1Q84 is a novel written by Japanese writer Haruki Murakami, first published in three volumes in Japan in 2009–10. It covers a fictionalized year of 1984 in parallel with a \"real\" one. The novel is a story of how a woman named Aomame begins to notice strange changes occurring in the world"));

        bookAdapter.setBooks(books);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: You are using a dependency that only works with compileSdk >= 34, and you are on 33. Either downgrade the dependency or update your own compileSdk to 34.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have changed the material version from "implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0' to implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'. and currently the project is running.

Comment: @jorn with all due respect, its not clear because it does not say what that dependency is. As has been commented com.google.android.material:material 1.10.0 was the problem, but you can't tell that from the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio error: "6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75122196/android-studio-error-6-issues-were-found-when-checking-aar-metadata) Same issue just update to v34 instead of 33 in that question from just 9 months ago.

Answer (score 87):

Replace this implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
```

with:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

Comment: Do you know what I can change if I have a compose project?

Comment: Saved me a lot of headace!

Comment: worked for me, THANKS

Comment: Version `1.9.0` of `com.google.android.material:material` seems also to work

Answer (score 25):

You only need to update `compileSdk = 33 to 34` in `build.gradle.kts`.

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same issue and downgraded material plugin from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

Now it's working fine.

Comment: You can also change it to 1.7.2

Comment: 1.8.0 is supported

Answer (score 8):

If you visit the Maven repository page for [material 1.10.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material/1.10.0), you will notice a section called 'Compile Dependencies.' This section lists the dependencies required for the material dependency to compile and function properly. Typically, these compile dependencies are automatically included when you declare the main dependency in your project.

The first dependency in the list is 'activity 1.8.0,' which is only compatible with 'compileSdk' versions greater than or equal to 34. To resolve this compatibility issue, you can either downgrade the material dependency or upgrade your project's 'compileSdk' version.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone's got the same issue these days, as a new version of Android Studio was released. All you've got to do is either change the value of `compileSdk` from 33 to 34, or downgrade the version of `com.google.android.material:material` from 10 to 9, that is, replace the line

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.**10**.0'

with line

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.**9**.0'

Either of the solutions are supposed to be applied in your *module*'s `build.gradle` file, not in your *project*'s one.

Answer (score 1):

Since last week, Android updated their activity version to 1.8.0 which requires you have the minimum sdkVersion of 34. If you change your version from 1.8.0 to 1.7.2, it will solve the problem because that version requires a minimum sdkVersion of 33.

Comment: I'm just wondering: if the activity version is set to a certain value *automatically*, why wouldn't they just make it so the `compileSdk`'s value is set to a certain value (34 in this case), too, so you don't have to change it by hand on every new project creation?

Comment: @bighugedev you are right. Google pretends everyone has the priviledge they have. Most of their apps that are recently made are like that and fail to make it in the market.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following changes to the **app** level `build.gradle` file:

```
- compileSdkVersion 33
+ compileSdkVersion 34
```

```
- targetSdkVersion 33
+ targetSdkVersion 34
```

**Note:** `-` = Line Removal, `+` = Line Addiation

Comment: It's great to give an understanding of why the change is required, maybe mentioning how the dependency is now restricted to targeting SDK 34 so you have to match that if you want to use the library?

Comment: Where? In what file, GUI place, or project setting? An answer should be self-contained (or at least contain the necessary references).

Comment: changes will be in the build.gradle file in your android project

Answer (score 1):

Basically the situation is: you current project using version 33, and you have conflict cause of this ->
'implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0' which require 34

Solution:

1. replace on : implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0' which will support version 33.
   OR
2. update SDK to 34

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue.
Then I checked my compileSDK version and target SDK version in build.gradle file in the Gradle Scripts Folder.
I changed

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.classify'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.classify"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

into this......

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.classify'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.classify"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I just updated the SDK version and clicked syn gradle button....
When i run the code now its promising

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I used the `compileSDK=34` already.

The problem was solved by checking all the implementations of mine. I had some older implementations which were still using the `android.*` dependency and not `androidx.*`. After I cleaned the implementations and changed them to `androidx`, the [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) build ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The recommended action is to update the project to use a newer *compileSdk*.

In order to do this, navigate to *Gradle Scripts* → *build.gradle.kts (Module.app)*. Replace compileSdk from 33 to 34. Press "Sync now" in the top right corner and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed the compiler version to SDK 34, and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the latest material library version and also don't want to target compile SDK to 34 then this is the solution for you.

Exclude activity from the material library as below:

```
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0") {
    exclude("androidx.activity", "activity")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed compileSdk = 33 to compileSdk = 34 in the build.gradle.kts file. After making this modification, I rebuilt the project and run the app. `compileSdk = 33 to 34`

Answer (score 0):

To solve, I had to update the Gradle plugin version. However, because Gradle plugin version which can be used depends on the Android Studio version, I updated Android Studio and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34` to gradle.properties file.