# Android studio giraffe download Oct 12 2023. 3 Errors show when using Empty Activity build

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

Doing tutorial on Android Studio Giraffe downloaded Oct 12 2023 but immediately get errors when new Empty Activity project tries to build. Hard to understand what the errors mean and how to implement the suggested fixes although I assume it means changing some files. How can anyone learn this when the simplest built in example code does not work. Here are the error messages.

3 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
   of at least 34, for example 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
   of at least 34, for example 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
   of at least 34, for example 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

Did not try anything yet, as suggested fixes in the error message need some context about where to make the changes. Also I could introduce more errors if I do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can downgrade version library to this version

```
androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2
androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1
androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2
```

or you can change version compileSdk and targetSdk to version 34 to clear the problem

Comment: Very new to Android studio because I want to go through the tutorials, which files would need to be changed to make compileSdk and targetSdk to version 34. Can you explain what the change would mean. Which file has the android xactivity etc statements in it.   Can you explain what that downgrade means? I will then try it and let you know how it works out

Comment: Or you want to change `build.gradle` /`build.gradle.kts` can change to this:

    compileSdk = 34
and

    targetSdk = 34
and then in `gradle.properties` you can add at the very bottom:

    `android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33,34`

Comment: I still can't explain why, because I also have the same problem, but if you want to solve the problem or error, maybe my suggestion can help.

Comment: Let's find out together the cause and the reason, I haven't opened the Android application for several months, it already has Compose by default haha ​​it's really fast

Comment: Very good, all I did so far was build.gradle /build.gradle.kts can change to this: compileSdk = 34. And this got rid of all the error messages. I did not change targetSdk. So now I can continue with a tutorial.

Comment: Oh really nice 

Comment: same question/reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283505/6629458